# Windows Phone 8: supports Native Unicode (Malayalam)?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I Want to make my windows phone 8 application support Malayalam Unicode

I want to use Native languages in my windows phone app. I have done it in android by loading the font files to asset folder. Is there any same way in windows to support the native languages? How can I implement this in the windows phone 8? if any ideas pls help me.

I want to build an app [like this](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/malayalam-reader/2505fc6c-b4e4-4d78-bf49-1adf1befee92?signin=true). This is an app using MALAYALAM an Indian language.

Comment: Have you tried something already? What didn't work? Share more details on your investigations, it will be easier to get help.

Comment: no am beginning to start, sure i will share when i got it.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following steps may help you:

1. Create a folder in your project called "fonts" (without quotes)
2. Copy your font file (*.ttf) in that folder. For example Arial.ttf (font name Arial UI)
3. Set "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer"
4. And use following syntax to access that font in your XAML

So, if your have Malayalam.ttf file with Hello World font in it, it will look like
FontFamily="fonts/Malayalam.ttf#Hello World"

You can find more infrormation here: http://blog.kulman.sk/using-custom-fonts-in-windows-phone-apps/

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Phone 8 Fonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202920%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

You are looking for

> Nirmala UI

which is one of the built-in Windows 8 Phone fonts.

[image]

Comment: Windows Phone 8 actually has a great number of built-in fonts http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202920(v=vs.105).aspx